# Поиск и вывод большего значения из json в python

Tags: python, json

Имеется код:

```
"fig": {
 "types": {
  "sizes": [{
  "type": "a",
  "val": 200,
  }, {
  "type": "b",
  "val": 500,
  }, {
  "type": "c"
  "val": 600,}
```

Известно, что типы делятся по значению val (если val >= 600, то выдается тип "c". Тип "c" имеет всегда большее значение, а "a" - меньшее из всех). Также известно, если val меньше 600, то в json списке создается только два типа: a и b.

Нужно реализовать код, который будет искать по типу максимальное значение и выводить его.

Концепция кода должна быть примерно такой:

```
если type 'c' имеется в списке:
вывести его
stop
поиск меньшего значения, type 'b'
если type 'c' имеется в списке:
вывести его
stop
вывести type 'a'
```

Comment: Приведите в вопросе данные, которые  вы хотите получить на выходе (в таком виде, в котором вы хотите их получить)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Во-первых, те данные, которые вы приводите, не являются корректным json - не правильно расставлены скобки и запятые.

Во-вторых, зачем нужно всё это "если с имеется в списке, то так, а если не имеется - то эдак" ?

Вам же нужно найти максимальное val, вот его и ищите:

```
import json

data = '''
        {"fig": {
            "types": {
                "sizes": [{
                    "type": "a",
                    "val": 200
                    }, {
                    "type": "b",
                    "val": 500
                    }, {
                    "type": "c",
                    "val": 600}
                    ]
        }}}
      '''

data = json.loads(data)

max_item = max(data['fig']['types']['sizes'],
               key = lambda item: int(item['val'])
               )

print("Тип с максимальным значением: %s" % max_item['type'])
print("Максимальное значение: %s" % max_item['val'])
```

Comment: В явном перечислении элементов списка необходимости нет. Достаточно `max_item = max(data['fig']['types']['sizes'], key = lambda item: int(item['val']))`. [Демо](https://rextester.com/NUVPB48874).

Comment: @AndreiOdegov, да, верно, спросонья немного затупил ) Сейчас поправлю.

Answer (score 1):

Вообще нежелательно делать именно такой список, но если у Вас только 3 значения (a, b, c), то тогда такой способ вполне подойдёт:

```
import json

with open('primer.json') as f:
    data_store = json.load(f)


def search(data):
    for l in list(reversed(data['fig']['types']['sizes'])):
        if l.get('type') == 'c':
            print('max val = c:', l['val'])
            return
        elif l.get('type') == 'b':
            print('max val = b:', l['val'])
            return
        else:
            print('max val = a:', l['val'])


search(data_store)
```